# Error SQL 979 with the group by

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with my Java EE/hibernate application.
This query works in my unit test, but not in my application.

```
    <named-query name="list.vacant.accessory">
        <query>SELECT proty, COUNT(acc.id)
                FROM ProductType proty, Accessory acc 
                LEFT JOIN acc.productHistoryList phl
                WHERE phl.status LIKE 'En stock ATOS'
                AND proty.id = acc.productType.id   
                AND phl.statusDate = (SELECT MAX(statusDate) 
                                      FROM ProductHistory ph
                                      WHERE ph.product=phl.product)                                       
                GROUP BY proty                    
        </query>
    </named-query>
```

I have this error : SQL Error: 979, SQLState: 42000

ORA-00979: not an expression GROUP BY

Have you any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know hibernate mapping. But purely from Query stand point:

```
 SELECT proty, COUNT(acc.id)
            FROM ProductType proty, Accessory acc 
            LEFT JOIN acc.productHistoryList phl
```

Here `proty` is referring to table / Entity and you are grouping by table name? Shouldn't there be a column name? `proty.column`?

Comment: You're right. With this syntax, it's better : SELECT proty.name, proty.id, COUNT(acc.id) ... ORDER BY proty.name